# Unable to Deserialize Json using C# Rest Sharp

Tags: c#, json.net

I am unable to deserialize a Json object via C#.

However, when deserialzing the data I receive an error message:

Content returned from Json Call:

```
[\r\n  {\r\n    \"postLogoutRedirectUri\": \"https://demo-pec.stage.reds.rxweb-pre.com/services/rxauthlogout\",\r\n    \"redirectUri\": \"https://demo-pec.stage.reds.rxweb-pre.com/services/rxauth\"\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"postLogoutRedirectUri\": \"https://stage.ecommsummitexpo.com/services/rxauthlogout\",\r\n    \"redirectUri\": \"https://stage.ecommsummitexpo.com/services/rxauth\"\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"postLogoutRedirectUri\": \"https://eventportal-new-stage.aem.rxweb-pre.com/services/rxauthlogout\"\r\n  }\r\n]
```

My RestSharp call:

```
public Rootobject getRedirectUris(string redirectUriGetUrl)
{
    var client = new RestClient(redirectUriGetUrl);
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
    request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
    request.AddHeader("accept", "text/plain");
    IRestResponse test = client.Execute(request);

    Rootobject object1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(test.Content); ;

    return object1;
}
```

My C# Classes

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public RedirectUriGetDto[] redirectUris { get; set; }
}

public class RedirectUriGetDto
{
    public string postLogoutRedirectUri { get; set; }
    public string redirectUri { get; set; }
}
```

I am receiving the exception message:  Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: ,. Path '', line 5, position 4.

Any ideas why this is occurring?  Is it due to the above not being valid Json?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Rob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of your `JSON` data is an array doesn't object.
You can try to use `IEnumerable<RedirectUriGetDto>` instead of `Rootobject`

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<RedirectUriGetDto>>(test.Content);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :-)

Comment: No problem glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You have to add parent Object in Json result:

```
    var object1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(string.Format ("{{\"redirectUris\" :{0}}}", test.Content));
```